# Class android.support.v4.net.* has already bee added to output

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated to Android Studio 1.0 RC 4 and it gives me some strange errors, but I can't figure out why.

The errors are:

```
Error:Class android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompatGingerbread has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
Error:Class android.support.v4.net.TrafficStatsCompat has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
```

And my build.gradle (the compile section) is:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    //compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:0.4.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0'
}
```

I've read in some others questions that it depends on two dependencies that share the same classes from `v4`, but I can't figure out which ones.

I'll hope someone can help.

Comment: Try clean and build your project again. Looks some silly mistake

Comment: Seems like clean&build don't solve the problem

Comment: SOLVED: the problem was a support-v4.jar in my lib folder

Answer (score 0):

First, try to update your jacksons versions your are using from **2.3.2** to `2.4.0`.
Here is your new code:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.0'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
//compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:0.4.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
//compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0'
```

}

It compile for me.

Comment: So try to comment com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.0